# Using Google Admin SDK, is there a way to suspend a user account (or to lock it in another way) that will still allow for the receipt of email?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-workspace

Please note that I have already looked at Google's documentation of user account suspension. As it is described, it does not quite meet a core use case that I need to address.

I need to figure out a way to inactivate/lock/suspend an account so that the user cannot log into it or access the resources that they own under that account but still allow the account to receive email (not allow the user access to the emails, just prevent any emails sent to the account from bouncing back). Basically I need all the functionality of suspending an account with that one exception.

I work at a large university and we are currently taking a second look look at how we manage G Suite accounts and access to them. We need a way to "deactivate" a user's account administratively (specifically using the directory API or a related API) so that the user cannot access it but still allow emails and calendar invites to be sent to the account while it is suspended or inactive..

For example (and this is our most prevalent use case, though not our only one), if an alumni allows their password to expire, after a certain number of days if they do not update their password, we inactivate/lock their university account. That user may however come back at any time and update their password, and once they do so, their access to their university account is immediately restored (the account is reactivated/unlocked). Our security group wants the Google accounts for these inactive users to be deleted because leaving them active poses a security risk, but since these accounts may be reactivated at any time, we do not want to delete the account and want to allow emails to still be received by the account even though the user cannot at that moment in time access the account (or the emails) or send emails.

Hopefully my question is clear. If any clarification is needed, please let me know.

Thanks so much for taking the time to address my question!

So, I am not sure why my question has been downvoted. As briefly mentioned at the beginning of my description, I've done the research (I know that I just mentioned the Google documentation, but I have looked on this site, a number of blog posts, other forums, etc.), and cannot find what I am looking for (hence why I am asking the question). I was simply wondering if there is anyone else that has already found a good way of doing this. I can hack something together that would probably work, but my hope was that there is a legitimate way of doing this that I am just missing since it seems like a use case that other organizations might have as well.